# What could be preventing the process callback from being called with an MTAudioProcessingTap?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, mediatoolbox

I've prepared an `AVPlayer` and `AVAssetExportSession` which both use the same `MTAudioProcessingTap` yet I cannot get either to call the `process` callback. I'd appreciate some help with identifying why the callback is not being called while others are.

I am simply trying to process audio with a tap so that it increases the levels by a scale to increase the volume. I am able to add the `audioMix` which includes the `audioTapProcessor` but when I run the app it only calls the `init` and `finalize` callbacks.

What is missing which is preventing the `process` callback from being run?

```
    var callbacks = MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks(
        version: kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0,
        clientInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passUnretained(self as AnyObject).toOpaque()),
        init: tapInit,
        finalize: tapFinalize,
        prepare: tapPrepare,
        unprepare: tapUnprepare,
        process: tapProcess)

    var tap: Unmanaged<MTAudioProcessingTap>?
    let status = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks, kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap)
    if status != noErr {
        debugPrint("Failed to create audio processing tap.")
        throw BoosterExporterError.failure
    }
```

I've published code on GitHub with the full project. Linked below.

https://github.com/brennanMKE/Boosted/blob/master/BoosterKit/BoosterPlayer.swift#L153

Answer (score 1):

Your need to find out the audio trackID and set it to AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters to make it work.

```
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioMixInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:self.audioAssetTrack];
```

See Apple's example here
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Listings/AudioTapProcessor_MYAudioTapProcessor_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012324-AudioTapProcessor_MYAudioTapProcessor_m-DontLinkElementID_6